# retrieving data from play-scala server

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, axios

We want to use REACT in a scala-play project. We'll, also, use AXIOS to send request from REACT (web browser) to the server. The question is, how could be a great way to create services on the play-scala server to respond to the requests coming from the web browser which could be using React?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

A **great way** would be to use the [*HTTP programming*](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHome) features of Play.